# Scala lower type bounds and covariance

Tags: scala, covariance, lower-bound

Im reading this page http://www.scala-lang.org/node/137, I understand what covariance is and lower bounds as well, but what it's not clear is this line:

> Unfortunately, this program does not compile, because a covariance
>   annotation is only possible if the type variable is used only in
>   covariant positions. Since type variable T appears as a parameter type
>   of method prepend, this rule is broken.

why `elem` has to be an instance of a supertype of `T`, if `ListNode` is already covariant why `elem` cannot be prepended to the current list.

Comment: The explanation is pretty straightforward. Type variable T appears as a parameter type. This is not a covariant position. What exactly poses a problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Super             {override def toString = "Super"}
class Sub extends Super {override def toString = "Sub"; def subMethod {} }
val sup = new Super
val sub = new Sub
```

Imagine the following were allowed:

```
// invalid code
class Foo[+T] {
  def bar(x: T) = println(x)
}
```

Since `Foo` is covariant on `T`, this is valid (a simple upcast, since a `Foo[Sub]` is a `Foo[Super]`):

```
val foo : Foo[Super] = new Foo[Sub] {
  override def bar(x: Sub) = x.subMethod
}
```

Now `foo` is, as far as we know, a `Foo[Super]` like any other, but its `bar` method won't work, because the `bar` implementation requires a `Sub`:

```
foo.bar(sup) // would cause error!
```

Comment: Ok, i understand, now from the line 'this program does not compile' form the scala site it, doesn't mean that we are actualy violating something in this particular code and we are not subclassing Foo[SomeClass] explicitly, the compiler is just protecting against a potential runtime error, am i wrong?

Comment: You're right, but it's just like the compiler applying any other rule of static typing, like not letting you call List methods on Strings. As the above shows, it would be logically inconsistent to allow a method's arguement to be a covariant type, so it doesn't let you.